# how to get a function's info in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

i often get argument mismatch error ,that usually take me a lot of time to debug program.damn, i really hope i know the function's entrance requirement and where they are come from.

since i only know a function variable is a function,no any other information.
i wrote massive codes like this

```
    public static function call(func:Function,params:Array = null,addToTailIfNotNull:*=null):void{
        if (func!=null){
            var args:Array =[];
            if(params!=null){
                args = ArrayTools.clone(params); 
            }
            if (addToTailIfNotNull!=null){
                args.push(addToTailIfNotNull);
            }
            func.apply(null,args);
        }
    }
```

i should do things more smartly .

Comment: Mostly you should know the number of your functions' arguments and their types beforehand. I actually expect this to be plain impossible, as any function can be called with an array on variable length like you do. Moreover, some functions have a mix of required parameters, optional parameters and ...args as an array of parameters with variable length. The type coherence is done in Flash at compile time, and only type coercion errors await those who pass incompatible parameters to a function at random.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you using flash.utils.describeType() method. It returns an XML with a description of an object you passed as a parameter.

Lets say you have a Class:

```
public class Example {
    public function someMethod(number:Number, string:String):void {

    }
}
```

And you call somewhere:

```
flash.utils.describeType(Example);
```

You should get an XML with something like this in there:

```
<method name="someMethod" declaredBy="com.example::Example" returnType="void">
  <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
  <parameter index="2" type="String" optional="false"/>
  <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
    <arg key="pos" value="501"/>
  </metadata>
</method>
```

I am not sure that this is what you looking for, as in your example if you pass you Function argument there you will get a description of Function class:

```
<type name="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure" base="Function" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Function"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="Function"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readwrite" type="*" declaredBy="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure"/>
</type>
```

But maybe you can refactor you "call" method so it could get the right description (for example pass additional info into it - like an object class and a method name - so you could analyse the method signature in it. Not the most beautiful solution, but still...)

Comment: This method requires a Class reference, while the OP has only a Function reference, without any information of its declaration, no class, no anything. And he actually wants to know what parameter(s) does the function that's accessible by given reference accept. So this won't work.

Comment: That's why I wrote "I am not sure that this is what you looking for". Some refactoring of the initial method ("call") is required to use describeType.

Comment: @Vesper The OP in fact does reference a class method however it is static. **public** static function call Public is after all part of a class definition.

Comment: thanks,no matter it's gonna work ,i will give a try,hope it working on anonymous function too.